# Sources/Prerequisites for DG

Tags: differential-geometry, advice, online-resources

I'm an graduate level in engineering physics, finishing my 1st year. This is what i have so far in math:

Calculus (single and multivariable)

Line integrals, green's theorem, vector fields.

Linear Algebra

Series

And this is what ill have next year:

Differential equations

Fourier series

Fourier and laplace transform, complex functions and vector calculus.

My questions are:
Am i ready to *begin* studying differential geometry, or should i wait a little bit longer? (I have a little bit of experience with analysis, but isn't anything very worth mentioning) i'm interested in studying differential geometry at home, so any other topics i didn't mentioned up there and you think is important to know before start thinking about DG, you're welcome to say.
Also, i have another question:
Are there any good sources of video-lectures and materials (such as notes, exercises, practice exams) that you guys can point me for start in DG? I tried MIT OCW but i couldn't find anything.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

I would say get three books. Any university multivariable calculus book (which usually hand wave details to make things accessible, but are very useful for attaching high-level theory to basic examples), Tu's book on manifolds, O'Neill's elementary differential geometry and O'Neill's semi-riemannian geometry. Although the latter is fairly advanced, since you're a physicist this is a great book for you to see where all the mathematics is heading.

Comment: Thanks for the book recommendations! Ill look after that. Do you know any online source of lectures? Thanks!

Comment: Ted Shifrin has his 3500-3510 multivariable course on youtube. Don't be fooled by the title ``multivariable calculus", in essence this course would serve as the best year long sequence for diff geo/top preparation.

Comment: Thanks! As for the prerequisites, do you think i'm ready to start?

Comment: You're ready. Just take it slow and keep learning mathematics.